# Non-blocking vs blocking Java server with JDBC calls

Tags: java, asynchronous, jdbc, nonblocking

Our gRPC need to handle 1000 QPS and each request requires a list of **sequential operations** to happen, including one which is to read data from the DB using JDBC. Handling a single request takes at most 50ms.

Our application can be written in two ways:

- **Option 1 - Classic one blocking thread per request:** we can create a large thread pool (~200) and simply assign one thread per request and have that thread block while it waits for the DB.
- **Option 2 - Having each request handled in a truly non-blocking fashion:**. This would require us to use a non-blocking MySQL client which I don't know if it exist, but for now let's assume it exist.

My understanding is that non-blocking approach has these pros and cons:

- Pros: Allows to reduce the number of threads required, and as a such reduce the memory footprint
- Pros: Save some overhead on the OS since it doesn't need to give CPU time to the thread waiting for IO
- Cons: For a large application (where each task is subscribing a callback to the previous task), it requires to split a single request to multiple threads creating a different kind of overhead. And potentially if a same request gets executed on multiple physical core, it adds overhead as data might not be available in L1/L2 core cache.

**Question 1:** Even though non blocking application seems to be the new cool thing, my understanding is that for an application that aren't memory bounded and where creating more threads isn't a problem, it's not clear that writing a non-blocking application is actually more CPU efficient than writing blocking application. Is there any reason to believe otherwise?

**Question 2:** My understanding is also that if we use JDBC, the connection is actually blocking and even if we make the rest of our application to be non-blocking, because of the JDBC client we lose all the benefit and in that case a Option 1 is most likely better?

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, you are correct -- non-blocking is not inherently better (and with the arrival of [Virtual Threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/8295817), it's about to become a lot worse in comparison to good old thread-per-request). At best, you could look at the tools you are working with and do some performance testing with a small scale example. But frankly, that is down to the tool, not the strategy (at least, until Virtual Threads get here).

For question 2, I would strongly encourage you to choose the solution that works best with your tool/framework. Staying within your ecosystem will allow you to make more flexible moves when the time comes to optimize.

But all things equal, I would strongly encourage you to stick with thread-per-request, since you are working with Java. Ignoring Virtual Threads, thread-per-request allows you to work with and manage simple, blocking, synchronous code. You don't have to deal with callbacks or tracing the logic through confusing and piecemeal logs. Simply make a thread per request, let it block where it does, and then let your scheduler handle which thread should have the CPU core at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

> Pros: Save some overhead on the OS since it doesn't need to give CPU time to the thread waiting for IO

It’s not just the CPU time for waiting threads, but also the overhead of switching between threads competing for the CPU. As you have more threads, more of them will be in a running state, and the CPU time must be spread between them. This requires a lot of memory management for switching.

> Cons: For a large application (where each task is subscribing a callback to the previous task), it requires to split a single request to multiple threads creating a different kind of overhead. And potentially if a same request gets executed on multiple physical core, it adds overhead as data might not be available in L1/L2 core cache.

This also happens with the “classic” approach since blocking calls will cause the CPU to switch to a different thread, and, as stated before, the CPU will even have to switch between runnable threads to share the CPU time as their number increases.

> **Question 1**: […] for an application that aren't memory bounded and where creating more threads isn't a problem

In the current state of Java, creating more threads is always going to be a problem at some point. With the thread-per-request model, it depends how many requests you have in parallel. 1000, probably ok, 10000… maybe not.

> it's not clear that writing a non-blocking application is actually more CPU efficient than writing blocking application. Is there any reason to believe otherwise?

It is not just a question of efficiency, but also scalability. For the performance itself, this would require proper load testing. You may also want to check [Is non-blocking I/O really faster than multi-threaded blocking I/O? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546273/is-non-blocking-i-o-really-faster-than-multi-threaded-blocking-i-o-how)

> **Question 2**: My understanding is also that if we use JDBC, the connection is actually blocking and even if we make the rest of our application to be non-blocking, because of the JDBC client we lose all the benefit and in that case a Option 1 is most likely better?

JDBC is indeed a synchronous API. Oracle was working on ADBA as an asynchronous equivalent, but they discontinued it, considering that Project Loom will make it irrelevant. [R2DBC](https://r2dbc.io/) provides an alternative which supports MySQL. [Spring even supports reactive transactions](https://spring.io/blog/2019/05/16/reactive-transactions-with-spring).

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: Even though non blocking application seems to be the new cool thing, my understanding is that for an application that aren't memory bounded and where creating more threads isn't a problem, it's not clear that writing a non-blocking application is actually more CPU efficient than writing blocking application. Is there any reason to believe otherwise?

Bear in mind that, in the synchronous model, if all threads are waiting on the database to return, then other processing of the requests is happening at all. If the amount of other computation required to fullfill HTTP request is non-trivial compared to the time of the DB call, then it will affect performance.